# Error al cachear partes de una plantilla con Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de trabajar con la caché de Django. Tengo una plantilla con una barra de navegación en la que si un usuario está logueado, aparece su nombre y si no, el botón para realizar login. El problema es que cuando hago login, no me aparece el cambio, y si ya estaba logueado y realizo el logout, se mantiene igual.

En la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) vi que podía añadir fragmentos de caché en la plantilla en cuestión por lo que el código de mi plantilla ahora se ve así:

```
{% load cache %}
.
.
.
{% cache 0 sidebar request.user.username|default:"nothing" %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<li id="actions">
    <a href="#" id="getActionsUser">{{request.user.username}} <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <div id="actionsUser">
        {% comment %} <div><a href="{% url 'users:update' %}">Mi perfil</a></div> {% endcomment %}
        <div><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}" class="logout">Cerrar sesión</a></div>
    </div>
</li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">Login</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endcache %}
```

Y en la vista lo tengo de esta forma:

```
@method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*24*7, key_prefix='main'), name='dispatch')
class PostsFeedView(ListView):
    """Code"""
```

Según interpreté la documentación debería estar haciendolo bien, le digo que genere una cache por cada usuario logueado y si no hay ninguno que le de un default de nothing que valdría para todos los no logueados pero por alguna razón no funciona.

¿Podéis echarme una mano?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema, interpreté mal la documentación. Para que funcione en este caso, hay que eliminar la caché que generamos desde la view, en mi caso, sería eliminar la siguiente línea:

```
@method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*24*7, key_prefix='main'), name='dispatch')
```

Y luego en la template para cada sección que quieras cachear, añades un bloque. En mi caso ya que quería cachear toda la template, tuve que crear varios bloques para separar esta parte de la navegación de las demás.